# Angular 4 Form Validation, submit button doesn't work

Tags: angular

Following this tutorial: https://github.com/designcourse/reactive-forms-tutorial and trying to implement a form that validates in Angular.

Everything works but the "submit" button.

When you click "submit", it does nothing. It should output on the screen what was entered for "firstName", "lastname" and "description." As it stands now it literally does nothing with no error in console or complier.

eligibility-validation.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-eligibility-validation',
  templateUrl: './eligibility-validation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eligibility-validation.component.css']
})
export class EligibilityValidationComponent {

  rForm: FormGroup;
  post:any;
  description:string = '';
  firstName:string = '';
  lastName:string = '';
  titleAlert:string = 'This field is required';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.rForm = fb.group({
      'firstName': [null, Validators.required],
      'lastName': [null, Validators.required],
      'description': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(30), Validators.maxLength(500)])],
      'validate' : ''
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.rForm.get('validate').valueChanges.subscribe(
      (validate) => {
        if (validate == '1') {
          this.rForm.get('firstName').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
          this.titleAlert = "You need to specify at least 3 characters";
        } else {
          this.rForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required);
        }
        this.rForm.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    )
  }

  addPost(post) {
    this.firstName = post.firstName;
    this.lastName = post.lastName;
    this.description = post.description;
  }

}
```

eligibility-validation.component.html file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- Form from tutorial https://github.com/designcourse/reactive-forms-tutorial -->
            <div *ngIf="!name; else forminfo">
                <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)">
                    <h4>Instructions</h4>

                    <p>Complete the following form to validate eligibility. Once received we will contact you to confirm the next steps.</p><br>

                    <label>First Name <input type="text" formControlName="firstName"></label><br>

                    <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['firstName'].valid && rForm.controls['firstName'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</div><br>

                    <label>Last Name <input type="text" formControlName="lastName"></label><br>

                    <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['lastName'].valid && rForm.controls['lastName'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</div><br>

                    <label>Description <textarea formControlName="description"></textarea></label><br>

                    <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['description'].valid && rForm.controls['description'].touched">You must specify a description that's between 30 and 500 characters.</div><br>

                    <label for="validate">Minimum of 3 Characters</label>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="validate" formControlName="validate" value="1"> On <br>

                    <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Submit Form" [disabled]="!rForm.valid">
                </form>
            </div>
            <ng-template #forminfo>
                <div class="form-container">
                    <div class="row columns">
                        <h1>{{ firstName }}</h1>
                        <h1>{{ lastName }}</h1>
                        <p>{{ description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <!-- End Form -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Console log and complier has no error messages.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: When you click submit, it does nothing. It should output on the screen what was entered for "firstName", "lastname" and "description." As it stands now it literally does nothing with no error in console or complier.

Comment: The div displaying the info is only displayed if the expression `!name`, used in `*ngIf="!name`, is falsy. There is no `name` attribute in your component, so it's always udefined, so `!name` is always true.

Comment: Put a debugger in your addPost() function to check if it gets called.  If it doesn't try changing `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` and add a click event to the button to call the addPost() function. i.e. `(click)="addPost(rForm.value)"`

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you -- that was an easy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JBNizet was correct in the comments: The div displaying the info is only displayed if the expression `!name`, used in `*ngIf="!name`, is false. There is no `name` attribute in your component, so it's always udefined, so `!name` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving below code from constructor to ngInit.

Normally constructor are class level but not in angular bootstrap cycle. it might be a problem its not set.

```
this.rForm = fb.group({
  'firstName': [null, Validators.required],
  'lastName': [null, Validators.required],
  'description': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(30), Validators.maxLength(500)])],
  'validate' : ''
});
```